# Would questions relating to things that I found in game files be allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I was going through a game's files and I found some files I wish to learn about. They are songs that I have not seen in game yet, and I was unable to find anything about them when I did some quick google searches.

I do not know if they are pertaining to un-released content however. Could I post a question regarding the files I found? Or should I leave it be for now.

EDIT: I believe I found the answer to the question I was gonna ask, though the meta-question is still valid in my opinion.

Comment: It depends on what the question is. We do have some [precedence](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/257891/145980) set for music found in the game files/soundtrack but not in the game. If your question is "Where does X song play", you're probably okay. If your question is "Why is X song never played in the game", that's off-topic.

Comment: @MageXy I feel like the case I am doing is an odd one. Ill add some more info to my question here regarding the game specifically, from how soundtracks are added and such.

Comment: If you put the question you want to ask here on meta, we can tell you if it's okay or if it's likely to be closed.

Comment: @MageXy alright. I am about to check something that may answer it. If what I am guessing isn't the correct answer, I will post my question here.

Comment: We've also determined that datamining isn't really something we cater to; it's generally seen as unreleased content, so coming at it from that viewpoint probably won't fly.

Comment: @Frank what defines data mining, getting anything from the game files directly, regardless of how easy or difficult they would be to get? For example, the files I based the question off of are .ogg files, though they were in a folder named Data.

Comment: We can't really draw a line on data extraction difficulty; its a pretty subjective level of skill. I think coming at it from the file standpoint would count as datamining, as you're asking about files from the game, instead of about the game itself. For example, see our meta question about Diancie; yes, the data was available, but there was no way to legitimately acquire the pokemon.  Asking about data found in a file seems to be a nonstarter, I think.

Comment: @Frank Alright, thanks for clarifying. Ill make sure to keep it in consideration when I think of making any other questions.